# Portlet title editing functionality into portlet body

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

As the title mentions, I was wondering whether there's a relatively simple way to use the functionality to edit the portlet title inside a portlet.

That is, when clicking a span contained in a portlet, it would then become editable (through an input box) in order to, then, update a portler preference.

This can probably be done from scratch, but since the functionality is already present in Liferay, there might be a way to make use of it.

Comment: Witch Liferay Version do you use?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it earlier, I'm using Liferay 6.2 CE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can update a `Portlet` title with a simple ajax call.

PFB the example`jQuery` code and mandatory parameters to be sent to update the Portlet title.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/c/portlet_configuration/update_title",
            method: "POST",
            data: { p_auth:'vcYb1DvX',
                    p_l_id:'10187',
                    portletId:'56_INSTANCE_hbJBswwx0rYg',
                    title:'My Webcontent'
            },
            success: function(data){

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
      });
```

Comment: Yes, something similar to that, coupled with serverResource is what I have implemented as a work around. What I'm trying to achieve is to use Liferay's in-built functionality - i.e. clone the title as a different element inside a portlet, to leverage the already built-in UI for editing the title and the respective permission checks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an "In Place Editor". For YUI (which is the underlying JS library for AlloyUI, bundled in Liferay), the first hit I get is [this project](https://github.com/elliotlaster/YUI-3-In-Place-Editor-Plugin), but with this search term you'll be able to find the component that suits your needs best.

Comment: Yes, something along those lines, but which leverages liferay's permission checking. I ended up building both the permission checking and the JS code from scratch, but it seems that checking whether the user is the portlet's owner isn't trivial as checking for the layout owner doesn't work as expected.

Comment: To add permission checks means some pseudocode like this:

`if(hasPermission) {
   generate in place editor with content
  } else {
   generate text-only content
}`

so it's not really rocket science. Liferay has a permission checker which honors configurable permissions, e.g. ties into the role-based Access control that you find. I'm not sure what else you need so that you'll have to roll your own

Comment: Yeah, that's how I have it implemented at the moment, the issue lies in checking for the permission on the backend. I want to check whether the current user is an owner of the portlet or a site admin:    `if (renderRequest.isUserInRole("administrator") || PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_TYPE_USER == portalUtil.getUserId(renderRequest)){
    hasPermission = true;
   }`. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get an owner id that matches the user that added the portlet.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt clearly understand your question. Still, i am answering your question.
In my project, we provide custom title where we will update the custom portlet title for the portlet by getting the name entered in the text box in my preference page using below code:
    // write this code in action method

```
PortletPreferences preferences = actionRequest.getPreferences();
String portletTitle= actionRequest.getParameter("portletTitle"); (title entered in text box)
preferences.setValue("portlet-setup-title-en_US",portletTitle); // update the portlet title      of  the portlet
preferences.setValue("portlet-setup-use-custom-title","true");// setting to receive custom title
preferences.store(); //stores the preference
```

Hope this helps